# How can I drag-drop files-photos to blu ray burner?

Tags: blu-ray, burning

I found it not possible to format a bluray disk and store misc files to it, why

Comment: I assume you are talking about Windows? Which version of Windows?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that most operating systems do not have built in support for Blu-Ray DVD burning. For an operating system to allow you to drag-and-drop files onto a CD to burn them, the operating system must support burning Blu-Ray disks.

The only way to actually do that is to use third party software that adds drag-and-drop support for Blu-Ray disks to the operating system. Alternatively, you could use a program (such as Nero) to burn the files to a Blue-Ray DVD.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen roxio do this. I don't know if it works with blue rays but it does have a nifty drag and drop interface.